# Create dataframe column using np.where or similar when criteria matches

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a dataframe column using np.where or similar when certain criteria matches as follows:

This linked [pickle file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32282382/data_df) is a segment of the data I'm using.  Here is the code I've used so far:

```
data = pd.read_pickle('data_df')
```

Data:

```
    Open    High    Low Last    Volume
Timestamp                   
2014-03-04 09:30:00 1783.50 1784.50 1783.50 1784.50 171
2014-03-04 09:31:00 1784.75 1785.75 1784.50 1785.25 28
2014-03-04 09:32:00 1785.00 1786.50 1785.00 1786.50 81
2014-03-04 09:33:00 1786.00 1786.00 1785.25 1785.25 41
2014-03-04 09:34:00 1785.00 1785.25 1784.75 1785.25 11
```

These are the time variables which I need to use in the np.where element:

```
#Times
daystart = '9:30'
dayend = '16:14:59'
IB_end = '10:29:59'

IB_session = data.between_time(daystart,IB_end, include_start=True, include_end=True)
day_session = data.between_time(daystart,dayend, include_start=True, include_end=True)
```

These are the high and low of these blocks of time:

```
IB_high = IB_session['High'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').max()
IB_low = IB_session['Low'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').min()
```

I need to write an np.where statement or similar to create new columns showing:

When `data['Last'] > IB_high` or when `data['Last'] < IB_low` and my statement needs to ensure that only one of these can happen per day.  A simple 1 in the column 'IB_High_Break' or 'IB_Low_Break' is needed to mark this happening.  This will eventually be used as a signal to enter a trade.

I tried using this:

```
data['IB_High_Break'] = np.where(data['Last'] > IB_high,1, np.nan);
data['IB_Low_Break'] = np.where(data['Last'] < IB_low,1,np.nan);
```

But get an error `ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare`.

What is a good way to do this?

Comment: If it is too time consuming providing an exact answer any other help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: I tried to include the original data but is it putting people off having to open a pickle file?  Should i ask the question again using random generated test data?

Answer (score 1):

If You have problem with lengths and could put data to same array, do it like here:...

```
>>> a = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
>>> b = pd.Series(np.arange(100,111))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([a,b])
>>> df = df.T
>>> df.loc[4.5]=nan
>>> df.sort_index(inplace=True)
>>> df.interpolate(inplace=True)
>>> df
        0      1
0.0   0.0  100.0
1.0   1.0  101.0
2.0   2.0  102.0
3.0   3.0  103.0
4.0   4.0  104.0
4.5   4.5  104.5
5.0   5.0  105.0
6.0   6.0  106.0
7.0   7.0  107.0
8.0   8.0  108.0
9.0   9.0  109.0
10.0  9.0  110.0
>>> df.loc[4.5,1]=0
>>> np.where(df[0]<df[1],1,np.nan)
array([  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,  nan,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,
         1.])
>>> np.where(df[0]>df[1],1,np.nan)
array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,
        nan])
>>>
```

Otherwise You need to do some iterations...

Answer (score 0):

I think I heard once that pickled files shouldn't be shared amongst unknown/untrusted entities as it's not build to be a secure deserialization, so this is answer is just based on skimming your code.

I think you get pandas.Series of inequal lengths, because your boolean creates a new pandas Series of length equal to rows that met your boolean, and therefore it is impossible for both `data['Last'] > IB_high` and `data['Last'] < IB_high` to have the same length as the row count in your data dataframe.

I would do something like this instead

```
data['IB_Low_Break'] = data['Last'].map(lambda i:  i < IB_low);
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: len() of unsized object` when using your code Asagen

Comment: Sry, my bad, I thought `IB_low` was a constant, not a Series.  If `IB_low` has the same row indexes as `data` then you can do it something like `data.apply(lambda i: i['Last'] > IB_low.loc[i.name],axis=1)`.  If row indices are not the same you set them to the same by doing: `IB_low.index = data.index`

Comment: I tried your code but get `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 7 elements, new values have 1774 elements
`

Comment: Hi, this is why I tried to provide a working example with included data (pickle file).

Comment: For next time you could always construct a toy example for which you didn't need to include a pickled object.  Anyway, my problem is that I don't quite know the objects you're using.  I assumed that `IB_low` was a Series and `data` a DataFrame with the same number of rows as `IB_low`

Comment: This is IB_low `Timestamp
2014-03-04    1783.50
2014-03-05    1790.50
2014-03-06    1797.00
2014-03-07    1795.25
2014-03-08        NaN
2014-03-09        NaN
2014-03-10    1790.75
Freq: D, Name: Low, dtype: float64`

Comment: When I use dummy data I'm often told to include the real data which is why I did on this occasion.  But as there was no answer to this so far I've asked a similar question here using dummy data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409962/pandas-trade-signal-columns