# Pandas trade signal columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add columns showing a value of 1 where a trade signal is seen.  I have put together the following test data to show what I am trying to do.

Create test dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
index = pd.date_range('2013-1-1',periods=100,freq='30Min')
data = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(100)), columns=['value'], index=index)
```

On 2013-01-01 we can see that between the times 09:30 - 10:30 the max value is 20 and the low is 19.

```
data.ix['2013-01-01 09:30:00':'2013-01-01 10:30:00']


value
2013-01-01 09:30:00 19
2013-01-01 10:00:00 20
2013-01-01 10:30:00 21
```

I want to create new columns called "enter_long" and "enter_short" that on each day will add a 1 the first time the max or min of `hour_1_session` (see below) is passed.  Only once per day so it can't have a 1 in enter_long and a 1 in enter_short on the same day.

This is the desired output and on this day it shows at 10:30 the value column was > the max of `hour_1_session` (max between the times 09:30 - 10:30).  In order to populate the enter_short column 'value' would have needed to be < 19.

```
                  value enter_long enter_short
2013-01-01 09:30:00 19    0          0
2013-01-01 10:00:00 20    0          0
2013-01-01 10:30:00 21    1          0
2013-01-01 11:00:00 22    0          0
2013-01-01 11:30:00 23    0          0
```

I can use the following to get this data but I don't know how to add new dataframe columns as per my question above:

```
daystart = '9:30'
hour_1_end = '10:29:59'
dayend = '16:14:59'

hour_1_session = data.between_time(daystart,hour_1_end, include_start=True, include_end=True)
day_session = data.between_time(daystart,dayend, include_start=True, include_end=True)

hour_1_high = hour_1_session['value'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').max()
hour_1_low = hour_1_session['value'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').min()

hour_1_high

2013-01-01    20.0
2013-01-02    68.0
Freq: D, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.  I changed a bit in the data generation code.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
periods = 48*7
index = pd.date_range('2013-1-1',periods=periods,freq='30Min')
data = pd.DataFrame({'value':[random.randint(0,100)+i/10 for i in range(periods)], 'enter_long':[False]*periods, 'enter_short':[False]*periods}, index=index)
daystart = '9:30'
dayend = '16:14:59'
day_session = data.between_time(daystart,dayend, include_start=True, include_end=True)

day_high = day_session['value'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').max()
day_low = day_session['value'].rolling(window=1,freq='D').min()
print(day_high)
```

day high for seven week period

```
2013-01-01     97.1
2013-01-02    104.9
2013-01-03    109.7
2013-01-04    113.5
2013-01-05    104.3
2013-01-06    121.7
2013-01-07    113.6
```

day low for the same 7 day period

```
2013-01-01     9.0
2013-01-02     7.3
2013-01-03    13.5
2013-01-04    18.9
2013-01-05    24.5
2013-01-06    46.6
2013-01-07    42.
```

Finds signals

```
for i, date in enumerate(day_high.index):
    df_sub=data[data.index.day==date.day]
    d = df_sub[(df_sub.value>day_high[i]) | (df_sub.value<day_low[i])].iloc[0:1]
    try:
        if d.value[0]>day_high[i]:
            data.loc[d.index,'enter_long']=True
        else:
            data.loc[d.index,'enter_short']=True
    except IndexError:
        print("No signals")

print(data[(data['enter_long']==True) | (data['enter_short']==True)])
```

Returns

```
                    enter_long enter_short  value
2013-01-01 01:30:00      False        True    3.3
2013-01-02 07:30:00       True       False  105.3
2013-01-03 07:30:00      False        True   13.1
2013-01-04 01:00:00      False        True   17.6
2013-01-05 00:00:00      False        True   24.2
2013-01-06 02:00:00       True       False  123.4
2013-01-07 02:00:00       True       False  129.2
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts Asagen.  Only problem is that I need this to be based around `enter_ short` or `enter_long` the first time the max or min of `hour_1_session` is passed. I can see your code is based on `day_high` and `day_low` and not the high or low of the first hour.  Is it easy to modify to be based on the first hour?  many thanks!

Comment: Oh, I thought the hour session was just for example purposes.  Yeah, it's easy, just change the slice for `df_sub`

Comment: Can you please show me how to change the slice? Thanks

Comment: This works really well thanks Asagen.  Marked as answered